# Adding ControlFX.jar file to build path

Tags: javafx, controlsfx

I am trying to install ControlFx for creating dialogs in my application. I have put controlsfx-8.x.x.jar file in the appropriate folder (lib/ext). It is the same folder where jfxrt.jar is present.
I am unable to add this jar to build path. The only option available is configure build path.

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to add the `ControlsFX` jar to JRE library(lib/ext) instead of your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controlsfx should not be put in lib/ext but simply added to your projects build path!